# Why express.js does not route binary file?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have a file I want to access at the following URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:400/db/signal/test.xlsx
```

And I have the following GET handler in my Express app:

```
app.get('/db/signal/', function (req, res) {
   // handle route
});
```

When I browse to `http://127.0.0.1:400/db/signal/`, the handler is executed. But when I browse to `http://127.0.0.1:400/db/signal/test.xlsx` the handler fails to execute. Why?

I'm using Express version 4.

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Express uses [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) to match paths. If you take a look at the API, you'll see that the string `'/db/signal/'` will only match *exactly* that path; it won't match any subpaths. To match that path *and any subpath*, just append an asterisk, like so:

```
app.get('/db/signal/*', (req, res) => { ... });
```

You can see more examples of matching patterns in the [Express routing guide](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-paths).

Comment: thank you @McMath. I changed code but when i enter url of file, be downloaded (does not run callback `{ //do }`).

Comment: I think we need more info then. Can you post the handler that sends the download? And can you show whether it comes before or after handler you show above? I just think we need more context if we are going to solve this.